# bash replace or append environment variables file local.env

Tags: bash, shell

I have a deploy script with comma separated environment variables like:

`script=/deploy FOO=BAR,ABC=XYZ,ENV=PROD`

and there is a .env file which contains content like:

```
FOO=NOTBAR
ABC=XYZ
ENV=DEV
```

I tried to create a bash script to parse the environment variables from `script` and replace or append them( if they do not exists in .env) in .env file. If the `KEY` exists in .env, replace it with new value and keep rest as it is. I tried to do with `sed` but that becomes too lengthy.

Comment: `sed` is the right tool for this kind of operation indeed

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with:

```
          script=/deploy FOO=BAR,ABC=XYZ,ENV=PROD
          if [[ $input_script == *"="* ]]; then
            parsed=`echo $input_script | sed 's/.*deploy//'`
            IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< $parsed
            for element in "${array[@]}"
            do
                new=`echo $element | cut -d'=' -f1`
                sed -i "" '/'"$new"'/d' .env
                echo $element >> .env
            done
          fi
```